# How to skip over an iteration in .map ionic 4 observables

Tags: observable, ionic4

I am working on an Ionic 4 app that pulls posts from the wordpress API. I am getting the featured image using mergeMap and forkjoin to get a posts featured image on the main posts page.

The following code works fine when there are featured images to get but if there are no featured images then I just get an error from my throwError. I can't seem to log the error.

```
ERROR Something went wrong ;)
```

Here is my home.page.ts files

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { WordpressRestapiService, Post } from '../services/wordpress-restapi.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  categoryId: number;
  private posts : Post[] = [];

  constructor(
    public loadingController: LoadingController, 
    private router: Router,
    private wordpressService: WordpressRestapiService) { }

  async ngOnInit() {
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create();
    await loading.present();

    this.loadPosts().subscribe((posts: Post[]) => {
      this.posts = posts;
      loading.dismiss();
    });
  }

  loadPosts() {
    return this.wordpressService.getRecentPosts(this.categoryId);
  }

  openPost(postId) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/post/' + postId);
  }
}
```

Here is my service file for consuming the wordpress api

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, forkJoin, throwError, empty } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WordpressRestapiService {

  baseRestApiUrl: string = 'http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getRecentPosts(categoryId: number, page: number = 1): Observable<any[]> {
    // Get posts by a category if a category id is passed
    let category_url = categoryId ? ("&categories=" + categoryId) : "";

    return this.httpClient.get(this.baseRestApiUrl + "posts?page=" + page + category_url).pipe(
      map((res: any) => res),
      mergeMap((posts: any[]) => {
        if (posts.length > 0) {
          return forkJoin(
            posts.map((post: any) => {
              if (post.featured_media === 0) {
                console.log('fired');
                post.media = {};
                return new Post(post);
              }
              else {
                return this.httpClient.get(this.baseRestApiUrl + "media/" + post.featured_media).pipe(
                  map((res: any) => {
                    let media: any = res;
                    post.media =  new Media(media);
                    return new Post(post);
                  }),
                  catchError(error => {
                    return throwError('Something went wrong ;)');
                  })
                );
              }
            })
          );
        }
        return empty();
      }),
      catchError(error => {
        return throwError('Something went wrong ;)');
      })
    );
  }
}

export class Post {
  author: number;
  categories: number[];
  comment_status: string;
  content: object;
  date: string;
  date_gmt: string;
  excerpt: object;
  featured_media: number;
  format: string;
  guid: object;
  id: number;
  link: string;
  media: object;
  meta: object;
  modified: string;
  modified_gmt: string;
  ping_status: string;
  slug: string;
  status: string;
  sticky: boolean;
  tags: number[];
  template: string;
  title: object;
  type: string;
  _links: object;

  constructor(values: Object = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, values);
  }
}

export class Media {
  date: string;
  date_gmt: string;
  guid: object;
  id: number;
  link: string;
  modified: string;
  modified_gmt: string;
  slug: string;
  status: string;
  type: string;
  title: object;
  author: number;
  comment_status: string;
  ping_status: string;
  meta: object;
  template: string;
  alt_text: string;
  caption: object;
  description: object;
  media_type: string;
  mime_type: string;
  media_details: object;
  post: number;
  source_url: string;

  constructor(values: Object = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, values);
  }
}
```

I have a check that if `post.featured_media === 0` then just return the post else make the api call to get the featured images but this never seems to return the posts. the `console.log('fired')` is called but the loadingCtrl never closes and the posts never show.

How can I just return an empty object for post.media if no featured image exists but return all the posts?

**Update:** Based on what David said I have updated the getRecentPosts() function in the WordpresRestapiService with the following. This gives me the result I was looking for.

```
getRecentPosts(categoryId: number, page: number = 1): Observable<any> {
// Get posts by a category if a category id is passed
let category_url = categoryId ? ("&categories=" + categoryId) : "";

return this.httpClient.get(this.baseRestApiUrl + "posts?page=" + page + category_url).pipe(
  map((res: any) => res),
  mergeMap((posts: Post[]) => {
    if (posts.length > 0) {
      return forkJoin(
        posts.map((post: Post) => {
          if (post.featured_media === 0) {
            post.media = new Media;
            return of(new Post(post));
          }
          else {
            return this.httpClient.get(this.baseRestApiUrl + "media/" + post.featured_media).pipe(
              map((res: any) => {
                post.media = new Media(res);
                return new Post(post);
              }),
              catchError(val => of(val))
            );
          }
        })
      );
    }
    return empty();
  }),
  catchError(val => of(val))
);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is you are adding a Post rather than an Observable of a Post to the array you are passing into the forkJoin.

You could try,

```
import { Observable, forkJoin, throwError, empty, of } from 'rxjs';
...
if (post.featured_media === 0) {
  console.log('fired');
  post.media = {};
  return of(new Post(post));
}
```

On a sidenote I'd avoid using catchError like that. It is essentially eating any javascript errors (as well as unsuccessful HTTP responses). It is why you are not seeing a helpful error in this case.

References:
(these aren't the official docs but I find them more readable)
Stack overflow thinks these links are code...

```
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/of.html
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html
```

Comment: Still not 100% on the catchError but I thought thats probably a different question in itself. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem @DannyConnolly. Basically what was happening is the forkJoin expected an array of Observables as an input. At some point it will throw an error, either intentionally, because it is type checking the input, or it will try to do something to your Post that causes an exception. At that point that error bubbles up to your code. If there is no catchError() it you will probably see that error somewhere (e.g. dev tools of your browser). With a catchError normal execution continues after the contents of the catchError is run (in this case logging 'Something went wrong ;)'.